# Flex Mobile: Single Instance for IconItemRenderer

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4.5

I've created custom [`IconItemRenderer`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/IconItemRenderer.html) in which label & message are being displayed over the icon (in my case it's a big image). I want to hide both label & message during the image is being loaded. So I made them invisible by default. And when image is loaded, I make them visible.

```
override protected function layoutContents(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
{
    super.layoutContents(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

    setElementPosition(busyIndicator, (this.width - iconDisplay.width) / 2, (this.height - Dimensions.BUSY_INDICATOR_EDGE_LENGTH) / 2);
    setElementPosition(iconDisplay, (this.width - iconDisplay.width) / 2, 0);
    setElementPosition(labelDisplay, iconDisplay.x + 20, iconDisplay.y + iconDisplay.height / 4);
    setElementPosition(textFieldProductNumber, iconDisplay.x + 20, labelDisplay.y + labelDisplay.height + 10); 
    setElementPosition(messageDisplay, iconDisplay.x + 20, textFieldProductNumber.y + textFieldProductNumber.height);

    setElementSize(busyIndicator, Dimensions.BUSY_INDICATOR_EDGE_LENGTH, Dimensions.BUSY_INDICATOR_EDGE_LENGTH);
    setElementSize(textFieldProductNumber, labelDisplay.width, labelDisplay.height / 2);

    iconDisplay.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onIconComplete);

    if(!isIconComplete)
    {
        busyIndicator.visible = true;
        iconDisplay.visible = false;
        labelDisplay.visible = false;
        textFieldProductNumber.visible = false;
        messageDisplay.visible = false;

    }
}

protected function onIconComplete(event:Event):void
{

    busyIndicator.visible = false;
    iconDisplay.visible = true;
    labelDisplay.visible = true;
    textFieldProductNumber.visible = true;
    messageDisplay.visible = true;  

    isIconComplete = true;

    iconDisplay.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onIconComplete);

    invalidateDisplayList();

}
```

Everything works fine, but if I push another View into `Navigator` and get back to the View where my IconItemRenderer is, system creates another IconItemRenderer instance, and nor label or message or image aren't visible (because of my default value).

So how can I use *earlier* crated `IconItemRenderer` instance?

or is it possible to use *single* `IconItemRenderer` instance (like a singletone)?

or is there any [`Event`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html) `Dispathcer` which indicates that data in item already exists?

Comment: It's usually helpful to show your code, in this case the code for your renderer, so we can get a better idea of what is happening.

Comment: Sure. Added code example

Answer (score 0):

Note that as an optimization for mobile devices, I believe the mobile item renderer classes do some caching of images (unlike on the web, where it just relies on the images being in the browser cache). This is likely why you don't get another COMPLETE event.

> So how can I use earlier created IconItemRenderer instance?

You shouldn't try or expect to reuse an earlier instance of the render. The Flex `List` control uses object pooling to recycle item renderers. The list creates as many renderers as needed to display the content on screen. When you scroll the list, it re-uses these renderers to display the new elements that have scrolled into view (more on this in a moment). You shouldn't try to circumvent this behavior, it's pretty efficient :)

> or is it possible to use single IconItemRenderer instance (like a
>   singleton)?

No, as stated above, the list uses object pooling and re-uses the renderer instances it creates as it sees fit. The singleton pattern really doesn't apply here.

> or is there any Event Dispathcer which indicates that data in item
>   already exists?

I'm not aware of an event that says "hey this image has already been loaded". However, when Flex uses an item renderer (whether it's the first time or when it's being re-used), it will set the `data` property of the renderer. The setter for the `data` property dispatches a "dataChange" event.

So you can listen for this event or override the setter for the `data` property to know  when the renderer is getting it's data. Now you have a two fold approach you can use:

When the data is set, determine if the data being passed in is calling for a new image or one that was previously displayed. If the data is different, listen for the COMPLETE event to know when the image is loaded as you're currently doing.

If the data is the same as before, just make the label/message objects visible.

This may or may not work... another idea is when the data is set, to try and infer if the image has been loaded by checking the `bytesLoaded` or `bitmapData` properties of the image.

By doing this sort of thing, you can make the image/label/message objects visible in the overridden setter method for data (or the event handler for the "dataChange" event) to handle cases where the image has already been loaded.

Comment: I've tried both variants, but in the first case there is no data about previous image. In the second case `bytesLoaded` equals to `NaN`, if Image was quered from `Cache`

Answer (score 0):

```
override protected function layoutContents(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
{
   super.layoutContents(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

   setElementPosition(busyIndicator, (this.width - iconDisplay.width) / 2, (this.height - Dimensions.BUSY_INDICATOR_EDGE_LENGTH) / 2);
   setElementPosition(iconDisplay, (this.width - iconDisplay.width) / 2, 0);
   setElementPosition(labelDisplay, iconDisplay.x + 20, iconDisplay.y + iconDisplay.height / 4);
   setElementPosition(textFieldProductNumber, iconDisplay.x + 20, labelDisplay.y + labelDisplay.height + 10); 
   setElementPosition(messageDisplay, iconDisplay.x + 20, textFieldProductNumber.y + textFieldProductNumber.height);

   setElementSize(busyIndicator, Dimensions.BUSY_INDICATOR_EDGE_LENGTH, Dimensions.BUSY_INDICATOR_EDGE_LENGTH);
   setElementSize(textFieldProductNumber, labelDisplay.width, labelDisplay.height / 2);

   if(iconContentLoader)
       ContentCache(iconContentLoader).enableCaching = false;

   iconDisplay.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onIconComplete);

   if(!isIconComplete)
   {
       busyIndicator.visible = true;
       iconDisplay.visible = false;
       labelDisplay.visible = false;
       textFieldProductNumber.visible = false;
       messageDisplay.visible = false;

   }
}

protected function onIconComplete(event:Event):void
{

   busyIndicator.visible = false;
   iconDisplay.visible = true;
   labelDisplay.visible = true;
   textFieldProductNumber.visible = true;
   messageDisplay.visible = true;  

   isIconComplete = true;


   iconDisplay.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onIconComplete);

   invalidateDisplayList();

}
```

I think this will solve the issue